# How can solve this integral

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, linear-algebra, statistics

[image]How ı can solve this integral, ı thınk that ı can seperate as above ı did but I dıd not do it, thanks for helping..

Comment: I would to rewrite the argument as a derivative with respect to $\eta$ and pull it out from the integral with respect to x, and then perform the derivtive w.r.t  $\eta$. That's the general method assuming $\eta$  Is constant of course.

Comment: I dont understand :(((

Comment: You are almost there, but remember, integration by parts is done to get something simpler, maybe you should choose other u and v.

Answer (score 0):

$\textbf{this for the positive values of x in the case of the other case }$

$\textbf{i.e. x<0 you swap the x sign but keep the general method.}$

$$
\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{x}{2\eta}\mathrm{e}^{\frac{-\left(x-\theta\right)}{\eta}}dx = \frac{\mathrm{e}^{\frac{\theta}{\eta}}}{2}\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{x}{\eta}\mathrm{e}^{\frac{-x}{\eta}}dx
$$
Now differentiation under the integral we find
$$
\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{x}{\eta}\mathrm{e}^{\frac{-x}{\eta}}dx = \int_{0}^{\infty}\eta\frac{d}{d\eta}\left(\mathrm{e}^{\frac{-x}{\eta}}\right)dx
$$
We can swap the differentiation and into integral operators around (as a physicist I trust this is true here, but some mathematicians have done the hard work and proved this works) therefore, this means that the integral is
$$
\eta\frac{d}{d\eta}\int_{0}^{\infty}\mathrm{e}^{\frac{-x}{\eta}}dx = \eta\frac{d}{d\eta}\eta
$$
which means that the integral equates 
$$
\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{x}{\eta}\mathrm{e}^{\frac{-(x-\theta)}{\eta}}dx = \frac{1}{2}\eta\mathrm{e}^{\frac{\theta}{\eta}}
$$
Do the same for x<0.